# AngularJS $http.get callign MVC Controller timing out after 3.8 minutes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, timeout

I'm not sure which is causing the timeout, but it fails consistently at 3.8 minutes ...

My AngularJS call looks like this:

```
$http.get('/Controller/Action/', {timeout: 20 * 1000 * 60})
```

And my controller set the ScriptTimeout to 20 minutes with:

```
HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout = 20 * 60;
```

What else could it be? It continues to run in the background, but the connection between the client and server stops at 3.8 minutes according to Chrome Developer tools Network tab.

Help! I really need this to return when it's done.

**EDIT**: This is running on Azure, if it makes a difference, I'm wondering if it overrides anything?

Comment: Is your server receiving the request?

Comment: Definitely, and it's working on it. It just takes ~5 minutes to complete, but the connection times out before it's finished (it continues working)

Comment: Try (1) taking out the timeouts and seeing what that gets and (2) setting the timeout to 2 minutes and seeing if it triggers at 2.

Comment: It was 3.8 minutes before I added those timeouts, and it still is.

Comment: What if you set the timeout to 2 minutes? Is it still 3.8?